# Incorrect Syntax in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I'm making a user login screen in c# winforms, I want to be able to check a user's username and password against records in an SQL database as per [this link,](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/baa85c20-7f6a-4c92-9917-24b6fa39ca67/login-form-using-c-and-sql?forum=csharpgeneral) however my code throws an exception saying "Incorrect syntax near User".

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code please? offending code is below.

```
 private bool CompareStrings(string string1, string string2)
    {
        return String.Compare(string1, string2, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0 ? true : false;
    }

    private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var username = textBox1.Text;
        //var password = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***********;Initial Catalog=*********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*********;Password=*******");
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = Conn;
            Conn.Open();

            com.CommandText = ("SELECT (Username) AS User, (Password) as Pass FROM dbname WHERE User='" + textBox1.Text + "'");
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            var username = textBox1.Text;
            var password = maskedTextBox1.Text;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (this.CompareStrings(reader["User"].ToString(), username) &&
                    this.CompareStrings(reader["Pass"].ToString(), password))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Authenticated!");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed!");

                }
                Conn.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: try writing User like [User] in query

Comment: Please use parameterized queries. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection by building that query with unsanitized user input. It also looks as though you're storing user credentials in plain text...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`USER` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[USER]`. **However**, the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

Always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

`USER` is an alias for `Username` column. You should use it's original name in your `WHERE` clause.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

```
using(SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand com = Conn.CreateCommand())
{
    com.CommandText = "SELECT (Username) AS [User], (Password) as Pass FROM dbname WHERE Username = @user";
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
    Conn.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Soner, this resolved my initial problem but before I mark as answered could you help me with another problem? it appears that my while loop in the above code will not fire when I try to breakpoint it, can you see any errors which could cause this behavior?

Comment: @Reece Check my answer there is error in your where clause

Comment: That in conjunction with this answer has resolved my issue, thanks for your help Gents; most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You must use Square brackets if you are using any keyword that is predefined OR Reserved by Sql Server

like here you are using `USER` you shall use  **[USER]**

and also your query is **wrong** you shall use **username** instead of **user** in `where clause`

You should use this

```
 com.CommandText = ("SELECT (Username) AS [User], (Password) as Pass FROM dbname WHERE Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'");
```